# How to resolve an error 503 .htaccess RewriteRule?

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2

I'm programming a website in php using Apache. You can see phpinfo() to [https://la-projets.univ-lemans.fr/~inf2pj01/phpinfo.php](https://la-projets.univ-lemans.fr/%7Einf2pj01/phpinfo.php)

I wrote a .htaccess file to rewrite URLs :

```
RewriteEngine On

DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

RewriteRule ^src/?.*$ - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^templates/?.*$ - [F,L]

RewriteRule ^login index.php [L]
```

The last line aims to redirect users asking for .../~inf2pj01/SAE3/login to .../~inf2pj01/SAE3/index.php.

On localhost, everything is working but in the la-projets.univ-lemans.fr env, this last .htaccess' line results in 503 error (Service Unavailable).
[https://la-projets.univ-lemans.fr/~inf2pj01/SAE3/login](https://la-projets.univ-lemans.fr/%7Einf2pj01/SAE3/login)

The index.php file is just :

```php
echo "cc";
exit();
```

Any solution?

Thanks

I tried to :

- remove all require() in index.php
- replace RewriteRule ^login index.php [L] by RewriteRule ^logzin index.php [L]. Result: 404 error
- replace RewriteRule ^login index.php [L] by RewriteRule ^login indzex.php [L]. Result: File not found.
  Note that the two previous errors are different from 503 error. It's like if login and index are properly found but an error occurs, I don't know why.

Comment: You need access to what php logs into the http server's error log file.

Comment: And ... just to be sure ... if you request `https://la-projets.univ-lemans.fr/~inf2pj01/SAE3/index.php` directly you do _not_ get a 503?

Comment: I do not have access to the logs. https://la-projets.univ-lemans.fr/~inf2pj01/SAE3/index.php is working.

Comment: I tried identical `.htaccess` and `index.php`, and it worked fine.

Comment: Be sure that **rewrite mod** is enabled. Put `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` at the beggining of your `.htaccess`, and `</IfModule>` at the end.

Comment: Or try `RewriteRule ^login/?$ index.php [L]`

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP The tests the OP made clearly demonstrate that the rewriting module is loaded and working. The rule does get applied, so also a trailing slash is not the issue here. Besides: the rule the OP uses would accept that slash anyway.

Comment: @EmilienEm_i I know that you do not have immediate access to the error log file. Since that is not your server. But usually within a university it is possible to directly speak to the admin of those systems and explain the issue. I usually got answers back in my time.

Comment: @EmilienEm_i It could be that some strange `RewriteBase` is set which causes problems here, since you implemented your rewrite rule based on relative paths. Try changing the implementation to absolute path or setting an own `RewriteBase`.

Comment: I tried RewriteBase too, not working. :/ I will contact admin servor.

Comment: Presumably you have no file that starts `login` (like `login.php` or something)? And no directory by that name either? "by RewriteRule ^logzin index.php [L]. Result: 404 error" - are you still requesting `/login` or `/logzin`? Please include the full HTTP response headers for the 503 response. Is this an Apache generated response?